# Need to stop sending multiple Attachments in emails in salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, email-attachments, apex

Every one I am trying to to send a email with attachment when oppoertunity is closed Won, but when I am trying to close more than one opprtunity at a same time then I am facing a issue that more than one attachment are send in a single email, So any one please help in to out of these probleam.

```
public class OpportunityPdfController {
        
       
    
    @future(callout=true)   
 

    public static void pdfGenration(Map<Id, Id> oppIdWithAccId){  
        Set<Id> OppIds=oppIdWithAccId.keySet();
        System.debug('OPPIDS'+ OppIds);

        Map<Id, ContentVersion> contentVersionMap = createContentVersion(OppIds, oppIdWithAccId);
        createContentDocumentLink(contentVersionMap);       
        
    }

    private static Map<Id, ContentVersion> createContentVersion(Set<Id> OppIds, Map<Id, Id> oppIdWithAccId){

        System.debug('OPPIDS2'+ OppIds);
        Map<Id, ContentVersion> contentVersionMap = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>(); 
        Blob body;        
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachList = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
        List<String> sendTo= new List<String>();
        
        List<Contact>  conList=[SELECT Id, AccountId, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN: oppIdWithAccId.values() AND Email!=Null];
        Map<Id, List<Contact>> ConMap= new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
        for(Id opp: oppIdWithAccId.keySet()){             
            ConMap.put(opp, new List<contact>());
             for(Contact cc: conList){
                 if(cc.AccountId==oppIdWithAccId.get(opp)){
                     conMap.get(opp).add(cc);
                 }
             }            
        }
       
        
        
        system.debug('conList'+conList );
        
        Map<Id, String> oppIdWithEmail= new Map<Id, String>();  
         
        for(Id OppId: OppIds){      
            PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/InvoicePDF');
            pdf.getParameters().put('Id',OppId);     
            
            ContentVersion cv=new ContentVersion();            
            try{   
                
                body=pdf.getContentAsPDF();
                System.debug('body : ' + body);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                
                body = Blob.valueOf('Text');
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
            }                     
            cv.PathOnClient= 'Invoice'+'.pdf';              
            cv.Title= 'Invoice'+' '+ Date.today();
            cv.IsMajorVersion = true;  
            cv.VersionData=body;  
            
            contentVersionMap.put(OppId, cv);    
          
        } 
        if(!contentVersionMap.Values().isEmpty()){      
        
            insert contentVersionMap.Values(); 
            for(Id oid:  contentVersionMap.keySet()){
                
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach= new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attach.setContentType('.pdf/txt');
                attach.setFileName('Invoice.pdf');
                attach.setInline(false);
                attach.Body = contentVersionMap.get(oid).VersionData; 
                attachList.add(attach);
                
            }
             
            For(Contact mailList: conList){                       
                
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage  mail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();               
                sendTo.add(mailList.Email);
                    
                system.debug('EmailList'+ sendTo);
                mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                mail.setSubject('Invoice');
                mail.setHtmlBody('');
                mail.setFileAttachments(attachList);            
                mails.add(mail);       
            
            }
          Messaging.sendEmail(mails);            
      
        }return contentVersionMap;      
          
    }

    private static void createContentDocumentLink(Map<Id, ContentVersion> idOppContentVersionMap){

            Map<Id, Id> idConDocMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
            List<ContentDocumentLink> ContentDocumentLinkList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    
            for(ContentVersion cv : [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:idOppContentVersionMap.Values()])
            {
                idConDocMap.put(cv.Id, cv.ContentDocumentId);
            }
    
            if(idConDocMap.isEmpty()) return;
    
            for(Id OppId : idOppContentVersionMap.keySet()){
    
                ContentVersion contentVersion = idOppContentVersionMap.get(OppId);
    
                ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
                cdl.LinkedEntityId = OppId;           
                cdl.ContentDocumentId = idConDocMap.get(contentVersion.Id);           
                cdl.shareType = 'V';
                
                ContentDocumentLinkList.add(cdl);
    
            }
            if(!ContentDocumentLinkList.isEmpty()){    
                insert ContentDocumentLinkList;            
            } 
     }   
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried send one email rather then multiple email when testing? the attachment based on your class might not captured the first email when send many email with attachments